# Keep a row together but break if necessary

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I´m working on a project using `XSL-FO` to generate some PDF Files.

There are several tables with rating comparisons.
Some columns have short text and some have very long text.

Without the attribute `keep-together.within-page` or with `keep-together.within-page='auto'` the tables look very ugly because the columns break the text at the end of a page - no matter what.

So i decided to use `keep-together.within-page='always'` to achive a better look. If a row doesnt fit on a page, fop moves the row to a new page. beautiful.

Now the problem.

In some cases some texts are very long and the content is larger than one page. In this case i want the row to break onto 2 pages.

I was looking for something like `keep-together.within-page='always if possible'`

is it possible to achive this some how?

Comment: What is the kind of text within a single table cell would be such that it is larger than a whole page? Does it not have blocks (read paragraphs) inside of it? Why not put the keeps on those if it does and not on the whole row?

Seems totally crazy to me to suggest you have a single, long table cell that is longer than one page that has no breaks inside it. If you do, no one will read it.

Comment: its a table filled with text with different length. Each row is a category. so i want to keep a row on one page if possible. But sometimes there is very much text in one small column which makes the row longer than one entire page. in this case i would like to break the row.

I could make every paragraph keep on page but in this case every row could be splitted on two pages. But i want each row to keep within page if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for:

```
keep-together.within-page='<number(1-9)>'
```

If you type in 'always' fop tries to fit it with any necessary method into one page. If you specify a number it is more like "I will try what I can, but if the text is to long, it will break anyways". The number you fill in, is more like a priority, in case you have many nested keep-togethers. That means that the value 1 will also do its job.

Comment: i thought that this number will priorities which element will keep-together if two or more elements wants to keep-together the higher number wins. But in my case this isn't the problem because i have only one object that does not fit completely on one page.

Comment: I would think you would also need to investigate which formatters support numeric weighting of keeps. I have no idea whether FOP does.